# Why is this Basic XPath Selector Not Working

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

Here's my basic structure:

```
<div id="PrimaryContentBlock">
    <form>
         ......
```

I'm trying to select elements from within the form, but XPath isn't finding anything past the primarycontentblock div.

The first query finds the parent node, but the second query finds nothing.

```
$dom->query('//*[@id="PrimaryContentBlock"]');
$dom->query('//*[@id="PrimaryContentBlock"]/form');
```

Any idea why XPath would be acting so strange? I've been seeing a lot of inconsistent behavior when working with DOMXPath queries.

Comment: you may have namespaces issues. Check if default namespace is mentionned in your structure (something like xmlns="...")

Comment: Could you show more of your HTML structure? Where do you get it from?

Answer (score 1):

One way this could happen is if you have an XHTML document (with an `xmlns` decalaration on the root `html` element) and you are parsing it as XML. In such a document all the elements are part of the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace, and you need to specify this when querying.

Your first query, `//*[@id="PrimaryContentBlock"]`, will find *any* element with a matching `id` attribute, including those in the XHTML namespace (that’s what the `*` means). The second query, `//*[@id="PrimaryContentBlock"]/form` is looking for `form` elements that are *not* in any namespace. This fails to match the document since all `form` elements are in the default XHTML namespace.

The simplest way to fix this, if this is an XHTML document, is to parse it as HTML. If you currently are doing something like:

```php
$domdocument->loadXML(...);
```

change it to use [`loadHTML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php):

```php
$domdocument->loadHTML(...);
```

If you want to parse the document as XML, then you need to specify the namespace in your query. First you need to [register the namespace uri and prefix you are going to use](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php) with the `DOMXPath` instance, then change your query to include the new prefix:

```php
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('xhtml', "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

$result = $xpath->query('//*[@id="PrimaryContentBlock"]/xhtml:form')
```

Comment: Try this `//*[@id="PrimaryContentBlock"]/*[local-name()='form']`. If it works, then it's a namespace issue.

Comment: Thank you matt and lwburk for the namespacing tips. I suspect namespacing could be to blame for some of the inconsistencies I've been experiencing. This current error was due to my own oversight. I built an initial XPath object for a previous document but didn't reset XPath for the DOM of the new document I was trying to query.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have the above structure, and you are sure that the document is well-formed both of your queries **WILL** work:

```
$xml = <<<EOF
<div id="PrimaryContentBlock">
    <form></form>
</div>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($xml);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach($selector->query('//*[@id="PrimaryContentBlock"]/form') as $element) {
    echo $element->nodeName;
}
```

Output:

```
form
```

---

If the following sentence is true for you:

> I've been seeing a lot of inconsistent behavior when working with DOMXPath queries.

... then you have either not enough expertise with XPath, or your input data isn't well formed. At least one those both reasons apply to me when I have problems with a certain query.